# My android application crashes after 10 tries

Tags: java, android

just starting out with Android and my problem is in a game I'm making. So I'm populating an image view with a picture of a dog, where the user has to guess the breed. So I figured out how to populate it but now I'm running into this issue where I can only re-populate the imageView 10 times before the app just crashes.

To be very descriptive,

I start the app, open the section which pushes you into this activity where the picture is shown and you have to pick the breed you think it is

I click submit to go to the next picture (rn its not checking whether the answer is right. It just runs the setup again and attempts to repopulate the Image View)

So I continue doing this and after exactly 10 tries, the app exits the activity and goes back to the menu activity. At which point I try entering the game again.

At this point in time. It either allows me to click submit once or a couple of times or maybe more but then crashes completely again and again.

#### Error Code

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.doggyroulette, PID: 17359
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7339)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14226)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7305)
        at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:846)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27787)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7094)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7339) 
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14226) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7305) 
        at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:846) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27787) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7094) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x1
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValueForDensity(ResourcesImpl.java:237)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:902)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:842)
        at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:628)
        at com.example.doggyroulette.IdentifyBreedActivity.appSetup(IdentifyBreedActivity.java:146)
        at com.example.doggyroulette.IdentifyBreedActivity.submitAnswer(IdentifyBreedActivity.java:167)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7339) 
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14226) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7305) 
        at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:846) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27787) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7094) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

#### Main Code

```
private void appSetup(){

        breeds = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.breeds);
        int randInt;

        //Hides Next Button
        nextBtn  = findViewById(R.id.nextBtn);
        nextBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        //Spinner Setup
        spinner = findViewById(R.id.breedDropdown);

        // ArrayAdapter to pass String Array list to Spinner, uses spinner_container.xml as layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerArrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.breeds, R.layout.spinner_container);
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);


        //Setup for Image View

        randInt = AppUtility.getRandomNumber(1, 10);
        Log.i("Rand_ID", String.valueOf(randInt));


        String filePath = "";
        correctName = breeds[randInt];
        switch (breeds[randInt]){

            case "Australian Terrier":
                Log.i("Breed", breeds[randInt]);
                filePath = "at_"+randInt;

            case "Beagle":
                Log.i("Breed", breeds[randInt]);
                filePath = "b_"+randInt;
                break;

            case "Boxer":
                Log.i("Breed", breeds[randInt]);
                filePath = "boxer_"+randInt;
                break;

            case "Chihuahua":
                Log.i("Breed", breeds[randInt]);
                filePath = "chihuahua_"+randInt;
                break;

            case "Cockerspaniel":
                Log.i("Breed", breeds[randInt]);
                filePath = "cs_"+randInt;
                break;

            case "Doberman":
                Log.i("Breed", breeds[randInt]);
                filePath = "db_"+randInt;
                break;

            case "German Shepherd":
                Log.i("Breed", breeds[randInt]);
                filePath = "gs_"+randInt;
                break;

            case "Golden Retriever":
                Log.i("Breed", breeds[randInt]);
                filePath = "gr_"+randInt;
                break;

            case "Great Dane":
                Log.i("Breed", breeds[randInt]);
                filePath = "gd_"+randInt;
                break;

            case "Labrador Retriever":
                Log.i("Breed", breeds[randInt]);
                filePath = "lr_"+randInt;
                break;

            case "Maltese Dog":
                Log.i("Breed", breeds[randInt]);
                filePath = "md_"+randInt;
                break;

            case "Saint Bernard":
                Log.i("Breed", breeds[randInt]);
                filePath = "sb_"+randInt;
                break;

            case "Schipperke":
                Log.i("Breed", breeds[randInt]);
                filePath = "schipperke_"+randInt;
                break;

            case "Siberian Husky":
                Log.i("Breed", breeds[randInt]);
                filePath = "sh_"+randInt;
                break;

            case "Tibetan Mastiff":
                Log.i("Breed", breeds[randInt]);
                filePath = "tm_"+randInt;
                break;

                default:
                    Log.i("Error", "Not Found");
        }


        final ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.questionImage);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(AppUtility.getResourceID(filePath,this.getApplicationContext())));


    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
    }



    public void submitAnswer(View view) {
        // Unhides Next Button after question has been submitted
        if(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(correctName )){

        }

        nextBtn  = findViewById(R.id.nextBtn);
        nextBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        appSetup();
    }
```

#### AppUtility Class

```java
import android.content.Context;

class AppUtility {

    static int getResourceID(final String resource, final Context appContext) {

        final int RES_ID = appContext.getResources().getIdentifier(resource, "drawable",
                appContext.getApplicationInfo().packageName);
        if (RES_ID == 0) {
//            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No application resource found at : " + resource);
            return RES_ID+1;
        }else {
            return RES_ID;
        }
    }


    static int getRandomNumber(int min, int max){
        int returnNum = (int)Math.round(Math.random()*max);

        while(returnNum<min){
            returnNum = (int)Math.round(Math.random()*max);
        }

        return returnNum;
    }
}
```

### Update :

So after uncommenting the throw new IllegalExceptionError line in my getResourceID() method. I now get this line of error which responds that the resource being passed to the method is nothing??

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.doggyroulette, PID: 25960
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No application resource found at : 
        at com.example.doggyroulette.AppUtility.getResourceID(AppUtility.java:12)
        at com.example.doggyroulette.IdentifyBreedActivity.appSetup(IdentifyBreedActivity.java:152)
        at com.example.doggyroulette.IdentifyBreedActivity.access$000(IdentifyBreedActivity.java:18)
        at com.example.doggyroulette.IdentifyBreedActivity$1.onClick(IdentifyBreedActivity.java:186)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7339)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14226)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7305)
        at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:846)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27787)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7094)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

#### It cannot be an issue with the image because I logged the numbers being passed into it through Log Cat and this is what went through. The last number is where it crashed.

```
2020-02-24 06:03:55.338 26898-26898/com.example.doggyroulette I/Rand_ID: 3
2020-02-24 06:03:59.716 26898-26898/com.example.doggyroulette I/Rand_ID: 7
2020-02-24 06:04:01.855 26898-26898/com.example.doggyroulette I/Rand_ID: 8
2020-02-24 06:04:03.455 26898-26898/com.example.doggyroulette I/Rand_ID: 5
2020-02-24 06:04:05.347 26898-26898/com.example.doggyroulette I/Rand_ID: 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x1
```

You are trying to find a resource whose ID is `1`. There will not be a resource with that ID, given the way that resources get numbered.

```
static int getResourceID(final String resource, final Context appContext) {

    final int RES_ID = appContext.getResources().getIdentifier(resource, "drawable",
            appContext.getApplicationInfo().packageName);
    if (RES_ID == 0) {
//            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No application resource found at : " + resource);
        return RES_ID+1;
    }else {
        return RES_ID;
    }
}
```

If your lookup of a resource fails, you return `1`. So, my guess is that your resource lookup is failing for your 10th item. Perhaps you are missing the appropriate drawable.

I recommend that you uncomment the `IllegalArgumentException` line and see if that gets thrown in your scenario. That would confirm that the failed `1` lookup is coming from `return RES_ID+1;`.

Comment: It is most definitely that line right there, but it doesnt make sense because after checking my image files as well, I can confirm that all the files have been appropriately numbered from 1 to 10. I just updated the question with the new error I got after uncommenting the line

Comment: Except that  your getResourceID returns 1 in the case of a failed attempt. It isn't finding a resources. Add logging to that method so you know the parameters that fail. Check for extra spaces on strings.

Comment: @NomadMaker I added Logs before the method, after the method and after doing so, I noticed that after another however many tries, no matter what number it generates there's a point where it cant return the resource ID. I dont get whats wrong